# What should we do to this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

For question [Why isn't Cricket an Olympics sport event?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16512/why-isnt-cricket-an-olympics-sport-event) rollback, we voted to close as duplicate of [How does a sport become an Olympic Sport?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/255/how-does-a-sport-become-an-olympic-sport) and now the edited question is getting reopen vote but still is duplicate of closed question with accepted answer [What are the reasons that cricket is not included in the Olympics?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2147/what-are-the-reasons-that-cricket-is-not-included-in-the-olympics).

So what will we do in this case. Should we reopen it and called it a duplicate of new one or anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd be tempted to just let it be. I'm not that bothered that a question which hasn't particularly attracted positive interest from the community is pointing to a slightly wrong duplicate, particularly when the current target is definitely a better question than the potential new target.

If there's a strong community feeling that we should retarget the duplicate, then we can do that one way or the other; the quickest would be for a moderator to use their binding votes to re-open and then immediately close again, but I'd always be slightly reticent to do that as it's skipping the community having a choice.